# Problem controlling ESP32 Cam with Python

Tags: python, esp32

I'm trying to use python to control an esp-32 cam.
After modifying my code (thanks alot to Dr.Casual for helping), I'm still having errors.

Here's my code:

```
 import cv2 as cv
 import numpy as np
 import urllib.request


# change to your ESP32-CAM ip

 url = 'http://192.168.99.10/cam-lo.jpg'       #hi or lo
 winName = 'CAM'
 cv.namedWindow("winName")

 while 1:
  imgResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  imgNp=np.array(bytearray(imgResponse.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
  img=cv.imdecode(imgNp, -1)

  cv.imshow("winName",img)
  tecla = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
  if tecla == 27:
    break


 cv.destroyALLWINDOWS()
```

Error codes are as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fangyaoting/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/esp32cam.py", line 13, in <module>
imgResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
response = meth(req, response)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: What does “indentation” mean and what are lines 13 brought 18?

Comment: @romkey that's just because he uses 2 spaces instead of 4*n

Comment: Are you running the "test script" for your URL and the source code from the same machine?

Comment: @user8408080 I know that. I was hoping they might figure it out with a bit of prompting. Of course now they’ve changed the question without fixing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP address `http://192.168.99.10/` does not exist and thus returns a 404. Check the URL within a browser to ensure it works, you should see the camera image.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I am able to see the image on my browser while connected to my wifi actually... The IP address works when I enter it into my browser, but I’m not sure why it’s returning a 404 here.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Replace the URL with yours and try.

```py
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import cv2

url = "http://192.168.0.131:81/stream"  
res = requests.get(url, stream=True)


for chunk in res.iter_content(chunk_size=120000):
    if len(chunk) > 100:
        try:
            img_data = BytesIO(chunk)
            img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(img_data.read(), np.uint8), 1)
            cv2.imshow("Face", img)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            continue
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```